# How to set up already consistent data for Google App Engine unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I know that App Engine datastore queries are only eventually consistent.  However, for some of my tests, I would like to seed the datastore with already consistent data (i.e. it was saved a long time before the test occurred and is now globally consistent).

How can I make sure that the initial data is consistent before running the tests?  I would like to still be able to require that actions under test do not require immediate consistency.

I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints for Java, but I'm not anything specific to Endpoints here.

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"  The anecdotal searching I've done so far on "eventually consistent Google App Engine data" suggests that "eventually" is defined as a relatively short period of time (less than a second, in most cases).

Comment: Rephrased my question.  The unit testing docs suggest setting unapplied job percentage to 100, which means that global (non-ancestor) queries will consistently fail to see changes, so I'm not sure just waiting works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating the following BaseTest class and having all of my tests inherit from that:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.HighRepJobPolicy;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;

public class BaseTest {
  public static final class Policy implements HighRepJobPolicy {
    static boolean shouldApply = false;

    public static void applyAll() {
      shouldApply = true;
    }

    public static void applyNone() {
      shouldApply = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldApplyNewJob(Key entityGroup) {
      return shouldApply;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollForwardExistingJob(Key entityGroup) {
      return shouldApply;
    }
  }

  public final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
          .setAlternateHighRepJobPolicyClass(Policy.class));

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }
}
```

Then tests can be of the form:

```
@Test
public void thingShouldDoX() throws Exception {
  Policy.applyAll();
  // Do setup here, everything inside will be consistent.
  Policy.applyNone();
  // Run code under test here, without consistency.
}
```